# iCal4j line break issues

Tags: ical4j

I have the following error when trying to open a .ics file created using ical4j.

net.fortuna.ical4j.data.ParserException: Error at line 132:Illegal property `[<BR />]`

I read the data from mysql which have line breaks(`<br>`). I get the same ParserException with `<br>` also. I replace them with `<br />`, create an event with the data and save it in .ics format. I get the above error when using CalendarBuilder.

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("test.ics");
CalendarBuilder builder = new CalendarBuilder();
Calendar calendar = builder.build(fin);
```

I tried System.setProperty("ical4j.unfolding.relaxed", "true"); also, but it does not work.

Can anyone help me figure out the actual issue here and solving it?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a data example my guess would be that you have a folded line of data but have somehow removed the space that should precede the folded line. This could also occur if you have a newline character in your text that is not properly escaped.

Try to examine your data and ensure that any content line that doesn't start with a property name is preceded by a space. And any newline character is escaped (eg. Double backslash)

Comment: Figured out the issue. It is an extra CR(/r) that is causing the issue. Works perfect after removing it.